# Does NPM package Concurrently really perform parallel execution elsewise how to perform parallel execution

Tags: javascript, multithreading, parallel-processing

So i want to run two scripts simultaneously in two different use case.

Case 1:

```
"scripts": {
    "start-watch": "nodemon run-babel index.js",
    "wp-server": "webpack-dev-server",
  }
```

Suppose we have two scripts in package.json and want to run them in parallel

Case 2:

```
var executed = false;
// loop 1
func();
// loop 2
func();

function func(){
    if (executed) return;
    executed = true;
    alert(1);
}
```

Now i want to execute these two functions simultaneous.

So can someone explain.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently unfortunately i don't test this library, could you please tell what the reason to run them simultaneosly?

Comment: Lets say we have a use case and curiosity

Comment: i think https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-parallel this one is your case